# Combine or wrangle columns in R to one column?

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a data frame made up id numbers, whether it is from an old or new system, and then a rule which gives 1 or 0 (I've just made that random for ease).

Is there a way of reformatting this so that I only get the 100 ID numbers in one column, old 1 or 0 in the next column and new 1 or 0 in the final column?

I've looked at group_by and pivot_wider / pivot_longer but I can't seem to find a way to wrangle it in this manner.

Appreciate any replies as always! This may be fairly simple but I can't see it.

```
# Create the Old/New column as a factor
old_new <- rep(c("old", "new"), each = 100)
old_new <- as.factor(old_new)

# Create the random column with 0s and 1s
random <- sample(0:1, size = 200, replace = TRUE)

# Combine the three columns into a data frame
data <- data.frame(id, old_new, random)
```

Comment: Show us your expected output.

Comment: Try: `tidyr::pivot_wider(data, id_cols = id, names_from = “old_new”, values_from = “random”)`

Comment: Also, please use `set.seed()` when using functions such as `sample`

Answer (score 1):

You should create an id by group first. Here, I use `consecutive_id` from `dplyr 1.1.0`.

```r
library(dplyr) #You need dplyr 1.1.0 or above
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
  mutate(id = consecutive_id(id), .by = old_new) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "old_new", values_from = "random")

# A tibble: 100 × 3
      id   old   new
   <int> <int> <int>
 1     1     0     1
 2     2     1     1
 3     3     1     0
 4     4     0     1
 5     5     1     0
 6     6     0     0
 7     7     0     1
 8     8     1     1
 9     9     0     1
10    10     1     0
# … with 90 more rows
```

Comment: That is eaxctly what I wanted, thanks. I missed mutate...